# My fresh installation doesn't load. (PulseAudio problem)

Tags: 11.10, boot, pulseaudio

I made a fresh installation of Ubuntu 11.10 beside an old W7 and another Ubuntu Installation.

When I started my netbook and chosed the new installation to boot, it doesn't load and it stops in a screen that says me:

```
*(...)
* Starting bluetooth
* PulseAudio configured for per-user sessions saned disabled; edit /etc/default/saned)
```

And the `*` symbol in the PulseAudio appears in orange, while other in other lined appear in normal white.

I would appreciate if anybody could give any piece of advise or orientation.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Same issue here, clean install of 11.10 "upgraded" to Studio through apt on Amilo Li2727.

Comment: Same issue here. 11.10 x64, after failed updates installation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also getting this after upgrade from Ubuntu 11.04 to 11.10 - in order to get it to boot I had to force use of the 2.6.x kernel instead of the v3 kernel that 11.10 seems to want to use by default.  I did this by editing `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` - not a great solution but it's a stopgap until I figure out why it's not booting with the v3 kernel and fix it.

For some reason I cannot use by USB keyboard with GRUB2 to select previous kernel from the boot menu, hence editing the `grub.cfg`.

**Edit:** Exact steps I took to solve this problem:

(1) Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> as boot starts to get a login prompt.  Log in.

(2) Navigate to `/etc/default/`

(3) Edit the grub settings: `sudo vi grub`

(4) Set `GRUB_DEFAULT=2>2`

(5) Set `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10`

(6) Save the file and run: `update-grub`

(7) Reboot.

Note, the `GRUB_DEFAULT` value is the 3rd submenu item in the 3rd submenu (counts from 0), which for me is the boot option for the latest 2.6 kernel.  If you have a new install yours might not have the 2.6 kernel available, or it may be in a different place, but I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thank you Strix dor your answer. I have never used the Sudo, nor navigate through the Bios in depth. Is it anything else I should know before I follow those steps?

Thank you for your time and attention.

Comment: What do you mean by "GRUB_DEFAULT=2>2"?