# Boot problem with Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: boot, pulseaudio

So, I am an Ubuntu newbie, and I don't know a thing about it. I tried to install restricted extras (am I using it right?) through terminal, but it seems I failed :) maybe because during installation the internet connection crashed... anyway, I restarted and I got the Ubuntu intro screen at the boot, and then a black screen appeared with this information:

```
checking battery state
```

I restarted and it showed something else, so I rebooted for 5 times. Then a screen appeared

```
*starting bluetooth 
*pulseaudio configured for per-user sessions saned disabled; edit /etc/default/saned
```

I tried this: [My fresh installation doesn't load. (PulseAudio problem)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67430/my-fresh-installation-doesnt-load-pulseaudio-problem) but didn't know how to save so I just skipped to update-grub, anyway nothing helped. What do I do?

Comment: Sounds more like X is failing, I think those messages are not the problem. Try booting to recovery mode and run `apt-get install -f`

Comment: Yes I am more with you bodhi. The messages might be a problem but the source of it which from what I could understand was an installation problem.

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned, when installing the connection got cut out and created a chain of problems afterwards. The solution is to do the installation again without having any problems while doing it (Power going down, hard drive in flames, etc..). But just to say it, if you start installing any OS and it fails while installing it at some point, you will probably have a corrupted system. Installing it again is your best bet.

Also while selecting to install the 3rd party restricted stuff make sure the internet does not go offline with you.

Comment: isn't there any other solution for the above problem. if no will my existing files on Ubuntu will get erased?

Comment: boot up with a live-USB and backup your files before you make a new install.