# Just Installed Ubuntu - Mostly empty screen that doesn't respond to mouse clicks or keyboard

Tags: 11.10

I installed (twice) Ubuntu x64 11.10 and it does boot (most of the time, sometimes it gets stuck with this problem [My fresh installation doesn't load. (PulseAudio problem)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67430/my-fresh-installation-doesnt-load-pulseaudio-problem))

The little startup sound plays, I see a background, and a toolbar left and a thinner grey one top. There's three buttons on the left one, nothing on the top. I can move the mouse cursor but no key press or mouse (left or right click) anywhere does anything. I don't know what's going wrong with it or what to search for to find a solution. I'm hoping someone has an idea from this description.

The hardware is relatively modern so quite possibly it needs some drivers or configuration changes:

intel DX79T0 motherboard
i7 6-core
ATI Radeon 6950

What steps should I try to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got around it by changing .dmrc Session=ubuntu to Session=gnome-2d

I then installed the proprietary driver for my Radeon card and restored Session=ubuntu and it worked after that.

Comment: btw, the problem still exists in 13.04, Ubuntu is broken out of the box with the open source driver on an AMD Radeon HD 6950

Answer (score 0):

Try yo install am early version, if it works, then upgrade to latest version, also you can try a x86 version