# How do install graphics drivers for radeon HD 6380g on a HP pavilion g6?

Tags: drivers, graphics

I installed ubuntu from wubi using a live cd but when i booted i just got a black screen so i followed the instructions from this forum http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10089820&postcount=8 which successfully completed the ubuntu installation but now when i boot ubuntu i just get a command prompt. when i type in startx it comes up with an error. I am told i need to install graphics drivers, how do i do this?
Thanks in advance
Ryan

Comment: I had almost the same problem. I had to install it from the ATI website manually.

Comment: how to i do this

Comment: I posted a walkthrough on how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(If you installed from Wubi and need to start recovery mode with nomodeset this could do the trick:
To make ubuntu boot with 'nomodeset' all the time you have to edit a wubi file inside Windows. In Windows open the file '\ubuntu\install\wubildr-disk.cfg' in WordPad
It'll look like this:
    loopback loop0 /ubuntu/disks/root.disk
    set root=(loop0)
    search --set=diskroot -f -n /ubuntu/disks/root.disk
    probe --set=diskuuid -u $diskroot
    linux /vmlinuz root=UUID=$diskuuid loop=/ubuntu/disks/root.disk preseed/file=/ubuntu/install/preseed.cfg wubi-diskimage ro quiet splash
    initrd /initrd.img
    boot
On the line that starts with 'linux /vmlinuz root=UUID=$diskuuid....' you have to add nomodeset after 'quiet splash'. Save this file and reboot.   )

Boot into Recovery mode, select option 'remount'. Drop into a root shell with network access (the 'netroot' option)

From the command line interface please type the following commands to install the newest amd driver:

```
login
```

(Just to make sure you are logged in as user not as root)

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge xorg-driver-fglrx fglrx*
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx*
sudo apt-get install build-essential cdbs fakeroot dh-make debhelper debconf libstdc++6 dkms libqtgui4 wget execstack libelfg0 dh-modaliases
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

This is just to make sure nothing you did prior to this walkthrough will corrupt the outcome.

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget --referer=http://support.amd.com radeon-crimson-15.12-15.302-151217a-297685e.zip
unzip radeon-crimson-15.12-15.302-151217a-297685e.zip
cd fglrx-15.302
sudo chmod +x amd-driver-installer-15.302-x86.x86_64.run
sudo sh amd-driver-installer-15.302-x86.x86_64.run
```

The installer will guide you through the installation, after it's done type:

```
sudo amdconfig --initial
sudo reboot
```

Your system should now boot up fine with a graphical interface

Comment: when i typed in "wget http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-driver-installer-12-3-x86.x86_64.run"  it said unable to resolve host address so all the commands after that didnt work

Comment: oh wait i didnt boot into recovery, will try that now

Comment: could you type 'ping www.google.com' to confirm that you have internet access. To stop the ping after a few packages hit 'ctrl+c'

Comment: i cant boot into recovery because the me thing happens when ii try a normal boot but i cant make it nomodeset

Comment: Wait I'll edit my answer for you real quick, because it's too big for a comment

Comment: it said unknown host www.google.com

Comment: i dont have that file i only have ".fuse_hidden0000000400000001"

Comment: My last idea on the issue: Boot up normally like you did before (with manually selecting nomodeset) to the point where you get the root command shell. Then type 'telinit 3' it should give you a login shell where you have to put your username and password (password isn't shown when you type). If this works try to proceed with the steps I put after the 'login' command.

Comment: when i type in telinit 3 it says "telinit:need to be root"

Comment: try sudo telinit 3

Comment: it worked but when i typed the URL it said "unable to resolve host address" just as it did earlier

Comment: that's at least some progress made...you are likely not connected to the internet (or at least ubuntu doesn't recognize your connection yet) if it isn't already try to connect your machine to the internet using a lan cable

Comment: when i type in "cd ~/downloads" it says it could not find it

Comment: so you successfully executed the command 'telinit 3' , after that you had to log in with your username and password. And now you should see at the beginning of each commandline something like 'your_username@your_machinename' can you confirm this? If it says 'root@your_machinename' please type login

Comment: it says "ryan@ubuntu"

Comment: okay...please type 'cd /home/ryan/Downloads' (carefull it is case sensitive! you have to start Downloads with an uppercase D). Do you have an internet connection working now? check by typing the ping command I mentioned above and see if it sends packages

Comment: I cant connect to my router until tomorrow because my sister is using the Ethernet cable. I will post back here when I get it back. shall I try the  'cd /home/ryan/Downloads'or wait till i'm connected to my router tomorrow?

Comment: the 'cd' command just changes you into the download folder on your ubuntu install. The commands mean the following: 1. (cd) Change directory to /home/ryan/Downloads. 2. (wget) Download the content available on the provided link (http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-driver-installer-12-3-x86.x86_64.run) 3. (chmod +x) Allow the downloaded file to be executed as program. 4. (sh) Execute the downloaded install script. The 'sudo' in front of most the commands just means they will be executed with root privileges.

Comment: i successfully installed the drivers and am now running ubuntu 11.10 :D thank you so much Daniel for your time and help

Comment: glad everything worked out for you. Could you please close the question by accepting my answer with the little check mark below the upvote buttons?

Answer (score 0):

You can install the graphics drivers for AMD graphics card by using the command (sudo) apt-get install fglrx. After the installation process completes, to be safe run (sudo) aticonfig --initial. Then reboot and it should work.

Comment: i tried these but after i typed the first one it said "package fglrx has no installation candidate" and the second one it said "aticonfig command not found" i also forgot to mention it doesnt bring up a command prompt it loads loads of things saying ...ok but it stops on battery...ok so i bring up a command promp using ctrl+alt+f1

Comment: Did you do (sudo) apt-get update first?

Comment: no but i did it yesterday and it says everything is up to date

Comment: i also did it after i typed in your two suggested commands and it said everything was up to date

Comment: You have to do it before you try to install anything.

Comment: when i typed in "sudo apt-get update" it came up with "failed to load..." and then a URL about 10 times and then it said "some index files failed to load" and then it said it had just used the old ones. If i helps when i get to the grub screen i have to press "e" and change "quiet splash" to "nomodeset" then it comes up with "*(...)
* Starting bluetooth
* PulseAudio configured for per-user sessions saned disabled; edit /etc/default/saned)" i then press ctrl+alt+f1 to get a command prompt and the i type in your commands

Comment: i think my problem is similar to this http://askubuntu.com/questions/67430/my-fresh-installation-doesnt-load-pulseaudio-problem but i dont know how to edit or get to that file