# ATI R7850 w. OpenCL support on 12.04+

Tags: server, ati, fglrx, opencl

#### Preface

I have downloaded the latest [AMD/ATI drivers](http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-driver-installer-catalyst-12.10-x86.x86_64.zip) for my Radeon HD 7850 and I am having a difficult time getting it to work with [ATI Stream SDK 2.1](http://developer.amd.com/Downloads/ati-stream-sdk-v2.1-lnx64.tgz).

I have tried purging **fglrx** and installing from debs created from the Catalyst installation script.  I have also tried simply installing directly from the script, vs generating and installing .debs.  After every installation, I run **sudo aticonfig --initial --nobackup** and then reboot my system.

#### Problem

The problem I am having is that **fglrxinfo** is giving me this error: *Error: unable to open display (null)*.  I have run fglrxinfo with my DISPLAY variable set to both :0.0 and :0 with no success.

Also, **DISPLAY=:0.0 ./CLInfo** only returns my CPU and no GPU.  My goal is to install my graphics card and have it shown in CLInfo so that I can use it for OpenCL.

#### System Information

```
$ lspci -nn | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Device [1002:6819]

$ uname -a
Linux Ubuntu-12.04 3.2.0-35-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 5 17:42:16 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "aticonfig Layout"
    Screen      0  "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" 0 0
EndSection

Section "Module"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
    Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Monitor    "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

- Ubuntu 12.04 (Server)

#### References

- [Bitcoin mining and Ubuntu 10-10 ATI Radeon 5xxx](https://foreverrising.wordpress.com/2011/04/16/bitcoin-mining-and-ubuntu-10-10-ati-radeon-5xxx/)
- [Ubuntu 11.04 Natty 64bit Headless Bitcoin mining with ATI 11.5 binary driver](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=9239.0)
- [Purging and Installing FGLRX](https://askubuntu.com/a/119990/13247)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get everything working by installing a lightweight X Window system.

> sudo apt-get install lxde